# BaseAdapter Custom Filter Trouble

Tags: java, android

Hi Im trying to create a `CustomFilter` for my `BaseAdapter` and am not having much luck .. i query my database for an array of the ID, Name and Sex. and on the `listview` i wish to search the list i have implemented the `textview` and have had no luck with the code.
here is my `CustomAdapter`

```
public class MyCustomBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private static ArrayList<Custom> AList;

private LayoutInflater inflat;

public MyCustomBaseAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<Custom> results) {
    AList = results;
    inflat = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

public int getCount() {
    return AList.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return AList.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    Long.parseLong(AList.get(position).getID());
    return position;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = inflat.inflate(R.layout.suspect_list, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.txtName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suspect_name);
        holder.txtSex = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suspect_sex);
        holder.txtId = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.suspect_id);

        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.txtName.setText(AList.get(position).getName());
    holder.txtSex.setText(AList.get(position).getSex());
    holder.txtId.setText(AList.get(position).getID());

    return convertView;
}

static class ViewHolder {
    TextView txtName;
    TextView txtSex;
    TextView txtId;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used `Custom Filter` in `MultiSelectionList`. Here is the [Code](https://github.com/Abhan/MultiSelectionList/blob/master/src/org/vcs/ecpvisit/CustomBaseAdapter.java).

Please download the demo, run and try to get understand and use that code as per your needs with modification as per your requirement.

Thanks.